# Error while running javascript program that takes input from user on visual studio code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

[image]

```
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();

var fname = prompt("Enter your first name: ");
var lname = prompt("Enter your last name: ");

console.log("Your full name is", fname, lname);
```

I tried running the above code of javascript on vscode and the error popping up is

```
node:internal/fs/utils:350
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENXIO: no such device or address, open '/dev/tty'
```

I have installed nodejs and javascript ES6 intellisense. I also ran the npm install prompt-sync command on the terminal before running the program.

Comment: Also please don't include misleading irrelevant Tags ("reactjs", "json"). I removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you ran the program in a terminal (with `npm start` or `node yourScript.js`). The error essentially means there is no terminal to take the input from.

If you run it through VS Code as a task then the *output* will be captured and displayed to you, but there is no interactive terminal attached that would take *input* for the program. That's why the program fails trying to open the terminal device.